# Querying an Array of docs (tricky)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Beginner here. Give me a `find()` query that will give age of "Sam"

Need to query the contractors array of documents. "name" field is a document that has fname: "Sam". But the "age" field is not in this "name" document, its in the preceding level doc.

Need a extensive query, that will work even if the position of "Sam" be any random position in a large DB

Expected output:

```
{age : 22}
```

```
{
    "name" : "Apples",
    "qty" : 120,
    "from" : [
        "USA",
        "Brazil",
        "Russia"
    ],
    "contractors" : [
        {
            "name" : {
                "fname" : "Sam",
                "lname" : "McGregor"
            },
            "age" : 22
        },
        {
            "name" : {
                "fname" : "zxc",
                "lname" : "asd"
            },
            "age" : 32
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `yourInput.contractors.find(c => c.name.fname === 'Sam').age` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- find the member of contractors with  `fname=sam` and `lname= McGregor` (if you want only the name, remove the name filter)
- and project to keep this matching members age
- use `findOne` method of your driver, because age will be the same in all anyways

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EumPgQWSf2u)

```js
find({
  "contractors": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name.fname": "Sam",
      "name.lname": "McGregor"
    }
  }
},
{
  "contractors.age.$": 1,
  "_id": 0
})
```

Query2

- aggregation solution
- match the fname,lfname  (needs multikey index to be fast)
- limit 1 because age will be the same anyways
- filter to find from the array the `Sam`
- project to keep only his age

*the difference from the above is that element match, saves the member that matched in `$` so we don't have to re-search for it.
But this solution will be fast if you have the mulitikey index.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70335078-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":  
    {"$and": 
      [{"contractors.name.fname": {"$eq": "Sam"}},
        {"contractors.name.lname": {"$eq": "McGregor"}}]}},
  {"$limit": 1},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "age": 
      {"$getField": 
        {"field": "age",
          "input": 
          {"$first": 
            {"$filter": 
              {"input": "$contractors",
                "cond": 
                {"$and": 
                  [{"$eq": ["$$this.name.fname", "Sam"]},
                    {"$eq": ["$$this.name.lname", "McGregor"]}]}}}}}}}}])
```

Comment: find() is giving
   [ { _id: ObjectId("61b7697adc481344f34babf0"),
    contractors: [ { age: 22 } ] } ]
aggregate is better giving: [ { _id: ObjectId("61b7697adc481344f34babf0"), age: 22 } ]
Just need figure how to get: {age: 22} only

Comment: mongodb always returns an array of documents, you will always get `[{...} {...} ...]`  i updated both answers to remove the `_id` also, to get the age from both, you will do it with your programming language. its easy to do. The aggregation returns now  `[{"age" : 22}]` you cant go any further with MongoDB, you should just take the first member and the value of the field age, with your programming language

Comment: You the Man ^_^